# To come down this way

Tags: phrases, verbs, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

This is from the movie Clean (2022)

> The rush of violence is better than dope. Better than blow, better than base. Meth. Crack. If you're lucky it'll let you come down this way.

I don't understand the last line at all. Does it have something to do with "to come down" as in "to come down from a drug and stop feeling its effects"? Seems to me it doesn't fit here. But then again I have no idea what it means then.

Comment: Just means to let you experience it, to amount to, to boil down to ... it all comes crashing down. Violence does not come down as a high to most. Hope it does this way for you.

Answer (score 0):

Drugs produce a rush:

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rush_(psychology))
>
> In psychology, a rush is an acute transcendent state of euphoria.

Taking drugs produces a *high*

> [NIH](https://nida.nih.gov/publications/drugs-brains-behavior-science-addiction/drugs-brain)
>
> These areas {the ganglia} form a key node of what is sometimes called the brain’s “reward circuit.” Drugs over-activate this circuit, producing the euphoria of the drug high

Hence, there is idea of coming down from the high, a comedown.

> [Drugwise](https://www.drugwise.org.uk/comedown/)
>
> Comedown is sometimes used to refer to the following day’s hangover from drug taking or drinking. More commonly used to describe the two or three day after-effects from taking ecstasy, though it can refer to other stimulant use such as amphetamine and cocaine.

Your quotation offers the proposition that experiencing the emotional and hormonal effects of violence will be a more agreeable way getting a rush and achieving a high than using drugs, and that the comedown from violence may be less unpleasant than the comedown from the listed drugs.